# Prioritize visible content - Page speed issue on Google insights

Tags: pages, css, optimization, google

I'm new to wordpress and i tried to speed up the site, but i got some error please see the image. I used w3 total cache,autoptimize and Above The Fold Optimization plugins. But still site is slow on mobile version. Please suggest me. Thx adv

[image]

Comment: The screen shot already tells you what to do: remove that script. Also quite funny that Google is telling you to speed up Google's own api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the fold now? to me, the fold is a little outdated, as it fully depends on the device/monitor size.

It may be that JavaScript in the header of your site is blocking the page load. The best way to combat this is to simply load the JavaScript in the footer of the site instead.

Comment: Please more details